# Arduino motor control

Tags: arduino, dc-motor

Can I connect a DC motor directly to an Arduino?

Comment: If it's a very *very* small motor, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The pins of the Arduino only can only provide a few tens of milliamps, not enough for a typical DC motor.

Pololu's line of [Simple Motor Controllers](http://www.pololu.com/docs/0J44/1) lets you control motors by sending serial commands from the Arduino (you can use the NewSoftSerial library).  The advantage of this method is that you can control multiple motors using a single pin on the Arduino.  The user's guide for these controllers comes with example Arduino code.

You could also get a simpler product such as a [motor driver](http://www.pololu.com/catalog/product/755), but then you would have to generate your own PWM signals and it would take more of your Arduino's I/O lines.

You're also going to need a battery or other power source; driving motors from USB power usually doesn't work because USB ports can only provide 500 mA.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to interface motors to the Arduino is to use an appropriate shield, like [this one](http://www.ladyada.net/make/mshield/).

Answer (score 2):

You will need some extra components:

http://www.tigoe.net/pcomp/labs/lab-motors.shtml

http://www.flickr.com/photos/irisphotos/5090745217/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an extra chip.

For $2.35 + shipping, I was able to control two motors using the [SN754410](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/315) using [this instructable](http://www.instructables.com/id/Duel-Motor-Driver-with-Arduino-using-a-SN754410NE-/) to wire it up. It's really easy.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, but maybe not because it's not powerful enough.
A DC motor, in general, is built such as when the commutator changes the polarity of the two halves of the coil, a short but very heavy current/voltage impulse is inducated (self-induction) that will basically burn the CMOS chips in the AVR.

If this is really a very small motor, you can avoid this current by adding an antiparallel diode between the AVR output and the ground (a so called runback diode) to short-circuit those inducated pulses, protecting the output of the chip.